# WSO2 Micro Integrator 4.1 does not update deployment artifact at runtime

Tags: wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

WSO2 Micro Integrator 4.1 does not update deployment artifacts at runtime

When I deploy .car on the running instance of MI logs says, that it's deployed, but when make a post request the old version of the sequence is called. Only restart the MI to solve the problem.

Expect, that sequences updated at deployment process at runtime without restarting every time

Comment: How did you deploy?

Comment: Just copy .car to carbonapps on server

Comment: Are your sequences saved in registry?

Comment: Yes, sequence in registry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The registry has a cache AFAIK, so once you deploy the new artifacts the registry artifacts will not load until the cache is cleared. A restart will clear this cache.

**Update**
Ok, I take the above claim back. This could be a bug in WSO2. Once you undeploy the CAPP registry artefacts should be removed. I found this [bug](https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/pull/1736) which is fixed in 4.2 it seems. If you have a subscription can you try updating the product? Or try using MI 4.2 instead of 4.1.

Comment: I will try to update and check it! Thank you!